# Proving Squeeze Theorem using Order Limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Would this be a valid way of proving the squeeze theorem using the Order Limit theorem?

If $x_n \leq y_n \leq z_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and if $\lim x_n =\lim z_n = l$, then $\lim y_n = l$ as well.

The order limit theorem states that if $a_n \leq b_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $\lim a_n \leq \lim b_n$.

So if I used this twice, wouldn't I obtain that $l  \leq\lim y_n \leq l$, which would imply $\lim y_n = l$?

Comment: To apply the order limit theorem, you first need to know that $\lim y_n$ _exists_.

Comment: As a relatively new user, you might want to look into [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It's a quick tutorial on MathJax. It will help you format your mathematical text.

Comment: From @DanielFischer comment it should be clear that Squeeze theorem can't be proved using Order limit theorem alone. It is much simpler to prove the Squeeze theorem directly (in fact its proof is much simpler than Order limit theorem). By assumtions given for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have an integer $N > 0$ such that $l - \epsilon < x_{n}$ and $z_{n} < l + \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. From $x_{n}\leq y_{n}\leq z_{n}$ it follows that $l - \epsilon < y_{n} < l + \epsilon$ for $n \geq N$ and therefore $\lim\, y_{n} = l$.